# dict into dataframe representation, dict of list and text entries

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I want to change a dict entry into a dataframe. Example:

```
data1 ={'Description': ['Python is an interpreted, high-level and general-purpose programming language. Python\'s design philosophy emphasizes code readability with its notable use of significant whitespace. Its language constructs and object-oriented approach aim to help programmers write clear, logical code for small and large-scale projects.[28]'],
    'Site': ['Wikipedia'],
    'Categories': ['Python', 'Programming']
    }
```

The output I want is something like this:

```
        Description                                          Site            Categories
0       Python is an interpreted, high-level and             Wikipedia       [Python, Programming]
        general-purpose programming language. Python's 
        design philosophy emphasizes code readability 
        with its notable use of significant whitespace. 
        Its language constructs and object-oriented
        approach aim to help programmers write clear, 
        logical code for small and large-scale projects
         .[28]
```

If I do `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1)`, I get this error

`ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

in which I fixed by

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1,orient='index').transpose()
```

However, two issues arose:

[image]

1st: the description is truncated. Only this portion of the text appears: "Python is an interpreted, high-level and genre..."

2nd: the output is split into two entries as in the image above.

How can I solve these issues?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the categories into list of list

```
data1 ={'Description': ['Python is an interpreted, high-level and general-purpose programming language. Python\'s design philosophy emphasizes code readability with its notable use of significant whitespace. Its language constructs and object-oriented approach aim to help programmers write clear, logical code for small and large-scale projects.[28]'],
'Site': ['Wikipedia'],
'Categories': [['Python', 'Programming']]
}


In[19]:  df
Out[19]: 
                                     Description  ...             Categories
0  Python is an interpreted, high-level and gener...  ...  [Python, Programming]

[1 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DataFrame` constructor you are using uses a `dict` where keys are the names of the columns in the `DataFrame` and for each key you have the values you want in that column inside a list if you want the value for the first row in the column category to be a list. Then the first element of the list associated to `'Categories'` must be a list. As a simple example consider:

```
data1 = {'Site': ['Wikipedia'],
         'Categories': [ ['Python', 'Programming'] ]} # list[list[str]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As you have only 1 item, you need to pass it into any iteratable object (it's one of the available variants). E.g.

```
data = [
    {
        "Description": "Python is an interpreted, high-level and general-purpose programming etc.",
        "Site": "Wikipedia",
        "Categories": ["Python", "Programming"]
    }
]
frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

2. The description is not truncated. The display is just a preview. If you choose description field via `frame["Description"]` you will see full content.